# link 2 subdomains in Firebase one for web and the other for dynamic links

Tags: flutter, firebase, hosting, flutter-web, firebase-dynamic-links

So I have already configured 2 sub domains in Firebase hosting and I have a Flutter web version app it's running on these domains but I also want to use dynamic links and I linked one of these sub domains to it and to my Flutter app but whenever I generate a dynamic link it navigates me to the web version

This is my firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      { "source": "/**", "dynamicLinks": true },

      {
        "source": "/links/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I tried to move the last part /links/ before the destination part but when generating the long url in the app I get the same error page wasn't found

this is my code :

```
  FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;

  Future<String> builDynamicLinks(String? id, {bool isFamily = false}) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      // The Dynamic Link URI domain. You can view created URIs on your Firebase console
      uriPrefix: 'https://links.nanny-finder.app/links',

      // The deep Link passed to your application which you can use to affect change
      link: Uri.parse(
          'https://links.nanny-finder.app/links/${isFamily ? "families" : "nannies"}?id=$id'),

      // Android application details needed for opening correct app on device/Play Store
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
          packageName: 'com.mickaelrobin.nannyfinderuae',
          fallbackUrl: playStore),

      // iOS application details needed for opening correct app on device/App Store
      iosParameters: IOSParameters(
          bundleId: 'com.mickaelrobin.nannyfinderuae', fallbackUrl: appStore),
    );

    final Uri uri = await dynamicLinks.buildLink(parameters);
    print(uri);
    return uri.toString();
  }
```

and this is firebase console
[image: Dynamic links console]

Comment: can you provide us with the configuration you made on the firebase console and the code you made in your flutter project related to dynamic links ?

Comment: According to your edits you have a misunderstanding between FirebaseDynamicLinks and (AppLinks for iOS , DeepLink for Android)

Comment: Can you elaborate ? I was trying to generate a link depending on the id I pass and I wanted it to open in the app itself but actually I got another issue with the not matching params with the url patterns in firebase console